# How to select items in JQ based on value in array

Tags: json, jq

I have a file with lines like this:

```
{"items":["blue","green"]}
{"items":["yellow","green"]}
{"items":["blue","pink"]}
```

How can I use [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to select and show only the JSON values that have "blue" in their "items" array?

So the output would be:

```
{"items":["blue","green"]}
{"items":["blue","pink"]}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found out the answer

```
jq 'select(.items | index("blue"))'
```

Comment: This is the best solution I have found so far dealing with data that has single list items as strings and there for not iteratable. Be advise, this is not exact matching.

Comment: what to use for exact matching?

Answer (score 11):

On Jan 30, 2017, a builtin named `IN` was added for efficiently testing whether a JSON entity is contained in a stream. It can also be used for efficiently testing membership in an array. In the present case, the relevant usage would be:

```
select( .items as $items | "blue" | IN($items[]) )
```

If your jq does not have `IN/1`, then so long as your jq has `first/1`, you can use this equivalent definition:

```
def IN(s): . as $in | first(if (s == $in) then true else empty end) // false;
```

### any/0

Using `any/0` here is relatively inefficient, e.g. compared to using `any/1`:

```
select( any( .items[]; . == "blue" ))
```

(In practice, `index/1` is usually fast enough, but its implementation currently (jq 1.5 and versions through at least July 2017) is suboptimal.)

Answer (score 5):

<strike>While what you have certainly works, it would be more correct to use `contains`.  I would avoid that use since it can lead to confusion.  `index("blue")` is `0` and one wouldn't consider that a truthy value and might expect it to be excluded from the results.</strike>

Consider using this filter instead:

```
select(.items | contains(["blue"]))
```

This has the added benefit that it would work if you wanted items with more than one match by simply adding more to the array.

As Will pointed out in the comments, this isn't quite correct. Strings are compared using substring matching (`contains` is used recursively) here.

In retrospect, `contains` didn't work out as I thought it would.  Using `index` works, but personally I wouldn't use it. There's something about figuring out if an item is in a collection by looking for it's index that feels wrong to me.  Using `contains` makes more sense to me, but in light of this information, it wouldn't be ideal in this case.

---

Here's an alternative that should work correctly:

```
select([.items[] == "blue"] | any)
```

Or for a more scalable way if you wanted to be able to match more values:

```
select(.items as $values | ["blue", "yellow"] | map([$values[] == .] | any) | all)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Though it will (dangerously) appear to work in some cases, it can also result in false-positives. "contains" is strictly a substring search. Counter-example: jq -n '["foobar","bar","baz"] | contains(["foo"])'   Results in true.    Compare with: jq -n '["foobar","bar","baz"] | (index("foo")==null|not)'   which correctly results in false.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Will, I didn't realize it ran the filter recursively for arrays. I'm sure there's a way to do this is intended while still being scalable.

Comment: I don't know if this would be scalable or not, as I suspect an iterative search is performed in all cases, but I have also previously used: `jq -n '["foobar","bar","baz"] | [.[] | select( . == "foobar" )] | length > 0'`  which at least has the *potential* to run the search in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

I have needed to use 'regex' for the same situation of the objects. (In another context, of course). I write the code because I did not find a solution for my need in these pages. This can be useful for someone.

For example, to match the blue color using a regular expression:

```
jq 'select(.items[]|test("bl.*"))' yourfile.json
```

[jqPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/5JHn1CIjBj)