# Exclude object if sub array contains n occurrences of a string with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have this

```
[
  {
    "title": "foo",
    "label": [
      "bar-one",
      "bare-two"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "foo_42",
    "label": [
      "bar-one",
      "bare-two"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "foo_42",
    "label": [
      "bar-one"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to count the occurrences of "bar" in array label
then exclude object if count > 1 (can be in 2part)

ex after process:

```
[
  {
    "title": "foo_42",
    "label": [
      "bar-one"
    ]
  }
]
```

I try different solutions, based on

[How to select items in JQ based on value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649960/how-to-select-items-in-jq-based-on-value-in-array?rq=1)

and

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/861

but I can't achieve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working:

Keeps only the items with a `label` property set to an array that contains only one occurrence of the substring "bar".

```
map(select(.label | map(select(contains("bar"))) | length <= 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reduce function taking the entire JSON as input and iterate over one object at a time and add it to the final result, only if there is one occurrence

```
jq -n '
    reduce inputs[] as $d (. ;
        if [ $d.label[] | select(contains("bar")) ] | length == 1 then
            . + [$d]
        else
            empty
        end
     )' \
json
```

The part `$d.label[] | select(contains("bar"))] |length` returns the count within the `label` array how many occurrences of `bar` occurs. We add it to the final result `. + [$d]` only if the occurrence is `1` or less than `2` which you can modify as needed.

Or the now deleted answer from [oguz-ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) which is equally neat and effective. Added here as a reference for future readers

```
jq ' 
   map(
     select(.label |
       any(., map(select(index("bar"))); length < 2)
     )
)' json
```